# How to split css shape in half vertically?

Tags: css, html

Please check out the jsFiddle link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/pnpHS/4/

As you can see its a yellow CSS shape.

How can I make it so its split in two vertically so the left side is that yellow colour but the other is transparent?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say transparent, does that mean that it will still be yellowish, or do you want all color stripped out from it?

Comment: So the transparent side has absolutely no colour.

Comment: I think you're really asking for half a circle.. ?

Comment: You can't split elements.  The word element itself implies an irreducible item.  You'll need to create another element.

Comment: @Steve Wellens You are right, elements can't be split, but the effect can be achieved without splitting it.

Comment: Maybe you're already aware of this, but for the sake of FYI: [border-radius: Safari vs Mozilla](http://www.css3.info/border-radius-apple-vs-mozilla/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a lot of limitations of what kind of shapes you can do while using a single element only (if you wrap it around another element, you can just use overflow hidden to wrap it).

To achieve it with a single element, you can do it by:

- Set `background` color to `transparent`
- Set a `border-left` to 50% of the elements width, using the a solid color as the color of the previous background color.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/pKuj9/

Comment: +1...I didn't think it was possible to do without adding another element.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot display only a portion of the shape you describe.

You can either describe a different shape or apply a mask over a portion of your shape such that it appears to  be not present.

Mask half of the shape with a second shape with the same colour as the background: http://jsfiddle.net/pnpHS/43/

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by defining the `:before` pseudo-class (of `::before` pseudo-element, if you opt to follow CSS3 specs).

http://jsfiddle.net/pnpHS/60/